What is the real "random"?
Let's think about a question:
Suppose $a_1 ,a_2, \cdots,a_n\in\mathbb{R^+}$, such that $a_1 +a_2+ \cdots+a_n=1$. Then randomly select a set of non-negative real numbers:$b_1 ,b_2, \cdots,b_n$, such that $b_1 +b_2+ \cdots+b_n=1$, then what's the expectation of $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\mathbf{1}_{a_i\leq b_j}$?
Where $\mathbf{1}_{a_i\leq b_j}$ stands for the flag function: $\mathbf{1}_{a_i\leq b_j}=\begin{cases}1,a_i\leq b_j\\0,a_i<b_j\end{cases}$.
Before calculating, I wonder that: What is "random selection", is it randomly select a point on the hyperplane:$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=1$, or randomly select a vector $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\in \{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)|x_i\geq0,|\boldsymbol{x}|=1 \}$, then form the set $(\frac{x_1}{X},\frac{x_2}{X},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{X})$, in which $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$.
The latter plan also means "randomly" select a point on unit sphere. So which one is the real "random"? Due to the geometric definition, again, what's "randomly select" a point on the hyperplane or unit sphere?

Good for you, spotting the potential ambiguity.  Of course, we have no way of knowing what those writers intended.  If you want a guess, I would assume they meant the uniform distribution on that compact region in the hyperplane $\sum a_i=1$.  Writers should always specify which distribution they had in mind. In this case, though, I think your second option might need some clarification.  Once fully defined, does it lead to a non-uniform distribution?

The default assumption is the Lebesgue measure (i.e. area), in other words your first option, if no context indicates otherwise.

You might be interested in reading about the Dirichlet distribution.

By randomly selecting, they mean that they are using a random vector $\textbf{X}=(X_{1},...,X_{n})$ valued in $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ which has uniform distribution over the compact set $\{(x_{1},...,x_{n})\in(\Bbb{R}_{+})^{n}:x_{1}+...+x_{n}=1\}$, i.e. the standard $n-1$ simplex. So what is the surface area of this simplex? It is given by $1/\Gamma(n)=1/(n-1)!$
So the distribution of $\mathbf{b}$ is given by the pdf $f(b_{1},...,b_{n})=(n-1)!\,\,,b_{1}+...+b_{n}=1$
For the point $\textbf{b}=(b_{1},...,b_{n})$ note that the projections $\pi_{j}(\mathbf{b})=b_{j}$ have identical distribution on $\Bbb{R}$ due to symmetry.
So for a fixed $i$, $E(\mathbf{1}_{a_{i}\leq b_{j}})$ will be the same for each $j$.
Now what is $E(\mathbf{1}_{a_{i}\leq b_{i}})=P(a_{i}\leq b_{i})$? Let us do the case for $i=1$.
Let us calculate what the distribution of $b_{1}$ is.
See that for \begin{align}f_{b_{1}}(b)&=\int_{b_{2}+...+b_{n}=1-b}f(b,...,b_{n})\,db_{2}...db_{n}=(n-1)!\frac{(1-b)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}\\\\&=(n-1)(1-b)^{n-2}\,\,,0<b_{1}<1\end{align}
So $P(a_{1}\leq b_{1})=(n-1)\int_{a_{1}}^{1}(1-b)^{n-2}\,db=(1-a_{1})^{n-1}$
So $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}E(\mathbf{1}_{a_{i}\leq b_{j}})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}n(1-a_{i})^{n-1}$$
Note that from the link for Dirichlet Distribution in the comments, you can get this special case by taking $\alpha_{1}=\alpha_{2}=...=\alpha_{n}=1$ and hence the Marginals have $\text{Beta}(n-1,1)$ distribution.
